# Pass a PHP GET into a JS function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a small PHP API which I use to grab different parts of info from my database.

From there I am loading the data into the table body with a JavaScript function. Part of loading this particular function requires a `$_GET['player']` passed through.

**The relevant JavaScript**:

```
function load_playerLogs(page) {
    var amount = $('select#per_page option:selected').text();
    var url = 'logs.php?action=player&player=&page=' + page + '&amount=' + amount;
```

the PHP/HTML file that loads the JavaScript function is for example:

```
index.php?page=logs&player=NAME
```

Is it possible to then get that `&player=NAME` passed into the JavaScript function so I can use my PHP API?

Comment: This might help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters

Comment: The above comment is correct.... As an alternative, you could echo the GET parameter into a JS variable like this: `var player = "<?php echo $_GET['player']; ?>";`

Comment: what is going to happen when `&player` is not set (for any reason) ?, I often find my page crashing in this case